# Updating multiple dropdowns with json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

What is good practice when storing an HTML select dropdown into a JavaScript variable. I also need to capture the value which they selected and pass that through.

I originally tried to use jQuery to create the option and hold it in a variable but it would error out.

```
var keyNamesList = $('<option></option>').val('').html('Select a Key');
```

I then used an HTML string and appended the options list in a loop with with more HTML represented as a string. See JSFIDDLE link for a mock up.

```
var keyNamesList = "<option value = ''> Select an item</option>"
keyNamesList += "<option value = '"+data.key+"'>" + data.value + "</option>";
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1v9h1dnn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<option></option>')...
```

Should just be `$('option')`.

PS: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Using a modal, the user is be able to add a record into the database. After posting to the database I need to update multiple drop downs with the new record the user added. To update the drop down I am making a call to the database to retrieve the list again.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that using an append per option and setting the value and content via the DOM API is going to cause a big performance hit, but just as general rule it's considered good practice to avoid multiple `append` and DOM mutation calls if you can, so I would normally build a single HTML string:

```
function getOptions(data, blank) {
    var optTpl = '<option value="%key%">%label%</option>',
        options = [];

    if (blank) {
      // if blank is truthy then append an option - if bool true then
      // a default label, otherwise use the value of blank as label
      options.push(optTpl
          .replace('%key%','')
          .replace('%label%', (blank === true ? 'Select one...' : blank))
      ); 
    } 

    $.each(data, function (i, datum){
        options.push(optTpl
          .replace('%key%',datum.key)
          .replace('%label%', datum.value)
        ); 
    });

    return options.join('');
}

// usage:
$('theSelectElement').append(getOptions(data, 'Select something!'));
```

I like to use a kind of template and call string replacements but you could build the strings on each iteration like you proposed in your question:

```
options.push("<option value = '"+data.key+"'>" + data.value + "</option>");
```

Example un-integrated with yours: http://jsfiddle.net/8tjwL6u5/